# How to let fmtlib do NOT raise exception when it meet a null string

Tags: c++, fmt

An example:

```
     const char* abc = nullptr;
     printf("%s\n", abc);
     fmt::printf("%s\n", abc);
     fmt::print("{}\n", abc);
```

in this example, it output :

```
(null)
(null)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'fmt::v9::format_error'
  what():  string pointer is null
Aborted (core dumped)
```

It's quite clear that fmt::print does not allow to print a char* which it's null.
Is there an easy way to let fmt::print accept that just as what fmt::printf do ? Print something or anything to let me know, just do not raise an exception and cause core dumped.

I don't want to change all fmt::print to fmt::printf in my project, there are too many.

thanks.

Comment: This is a known issue https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/issues/226

Comment: @康桓瑋 I read this issue,  it seems just about fmt::printf but not about fmt::print. Maybe they are not the same.

Comment: `std::printf` of a null pointer is considered UB. Basically you should never have it in the first place.

Comment: You should change all uses of it into a macro/function that checks for nullptr, or fix your program so that it won't try to print a nullptr. .... that's the main bug here

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the string in your type and write a formatter for it that handles null differently. For example:

```
#include <fmt/format.h>

namespace my {
struct nullable {
  const char* str;
  explicit nullable(const char* s) : str(s) {}
};

auto format_as(nullable n) { return n.str ? n.str : "(null)"; }
}

int main() {
  const char* s = nullptr;
  fmt::print("{}", my::nullable(s));
}
```

This prints `(null)`.

https://godbolt.org/z/Er7TW4ff9